# Docker swarm run on multible machines

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-swarm, docker-image

I deploy a docker swarm on 5 nodes and I have 5 microservices. The docker swarm assigns the services only in one node. Is there is any way to tell to docker swarm which node to use for every service in order to assign 1 service in every node.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this with the ["deploy" configuration option](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/deploy/) in your compose file. For example:

```
deploy:
  placement:
    constraints:
    - "node.hostname == desired_machine_hostname"
```